# How can I "cat" a file and remove commented lines?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, cat, replace

I'd like to know if there is a way that I could `cat` file like `php.ini` and remove all lines starting with `;`

For example, if the file contained this:

```
;   - Show all errors, except for notices
;
;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;
;   - Show only errors
;
;error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
;
;   - Show all errors except for notices
;
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

and I ran the correct command `cat | {remove comments command}`, then I would end up with:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

**Note** - I assumed that `cat` would be the best way to do this but I'm actually fine with the answer using another utility like `awk`, `sed`, `egrep`, etc.

Comment: What about something like `error_reporting = E_ALL & E_NOTICE ; Show all errors, except for notices`? Should the comment be removed in that case as well?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I'm really fine with just lines starting with comments being removed

Comment: `cat` is the tool to concatenate files. `grep` is the tool to filter lines based on patterns. `sed` and `awk` can also modify those lines.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -e '/^;/d' php.ini
```

Answer (score 44):

You don't need to pipe a file thru grep, grep takes filename(s) as command line args.

```
grep -v '^#' file1 file2 file3
```

will print all lines EXCEPT those that begin with a # char.
you can change the comment char to whatever you wish.

If you have more than one comment char (assuming its at the beginning of a line)

```
egrep -v '^(;|#|//)' filelist
```

Comment: Another one I've done that always stuck with me was `grep '^[^;]' filename`. I can't speak to its portability though!

Comment: @JodieC, that's portable but also removes empty lines (Which is often desired). The standard equivalent of `egrep` is `grep -E`. One can also use `grep -ve '^[;#]' -e '^//'`

Comment: if you want to remove blank lines, and also line with spaces before the '#' you can do: `grep -ve '\s*#' -e '^$' filename`

Answer (score 10):

`egrep` can save you the use of `cat`. In other words, create less processes (`egrep` vs `cat`+`egrep`) and use less buffers (pipe from `cat` to `egrep` vs no pipe).

It is generally a good idea to limit the use of `cat` if you simply want to pass a file to a command that can read it on its own.

With this said, the following command will remove comments, even if they are indented with spaces or tabs:

```
egrep -v '^[[:blank:]]*;' file.ini
```

Comment: Funny that you combine the newer `[[` *character class*  `]]` regex format with the use of the `egrep` command deprecated for at least a decade or so.

Comment: Interesting... current docs at https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html include POSIX classes.

Answer (score 9):

```
egrep -v '^;|^$' $file
```

that will exclude lines that begin with the ';', and empty lines.

in regex, `^` indicates the beginning of a line, and `$` the end of a line, so `^$` specifies lines where the start of line character and the end of line character are right next to each other.

Comment: so if i'm reading this right this can remove commented lines, but also blank lines?

Comment: @cwd Yes. I'm not sure why he included both, but if you only want to remove commented lines just use `egrep -v '^;'`

Comment: egrep likes files too (less processes and buffers used), and a little bonus would be to remove indented comments too: `egrep -v '^[[:blank:]]*;' file.ini`

Comment: We need a "useless use of cat" badge.

Comment: @nrolans - looks like a popular comment, why not make it an answer?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek i included both, just because if you're performing this action on a long file, like a stock httpd.conf, or something, excluding commented lines often leaves large blocks of whitespace lines between the lines with real content.  so, generally, i find it more useful to filter both comment lines, and whitespace lines, even though it wasn't exactly to the letter of the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -Ev ^'(#|$)' file.txt
```

Strips all comments and empty lines from file.txt

Updated answer per Yokai's comment. "Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified."  ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: You should consider expanding your answer with a little more information for the uninitiated (e.g., exactly what the regex you use does).

Comment: `egrep` is depreciated. Use `grep -Ev` instead.

Comment: This is the tightest, most elegant answer. Thanks Nikola!

Answer (score 2):

A simple `awk` one-liner `awk '/^;/{next}1' input_file` should do the trick.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
;   - Show all errors, except for notices
;
;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;
;   - Show only errors
;
;error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
;
;   - Show all errors except for notices
;
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/^;/{next}1' file
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
[jaypal:~/Temp]
```

Comment: Correct, but verbose. Just `awk '!/^;/' input_file` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

As well as Jaypal, I also most probably would use `awk` for these purposes. 
It worse to mention that perl is sometimes quite handy for such purposes:

```
cat data.txt | perl -lne "print unless /^;/"
```

Perl regexps are more powerful compared to awk's one and sometimes you might need them.

Comment: +1 for perl, although the cat and the -l are both redundant, so a simpler invocation is `perl -ne 'print unless /^;/' data.txt`

Comment: @Simone Whitaker, yes, you are right - it is just a habit to write it the way i write, and it worth to mention it.

Comment: Sure thing. In fact, I think `cat` works fine in these examples if you consider it as a proxy for the more generic "anything generating text on STDOUT". Unix pipes are the best thing since sliced bread, imho. :)

Answer (score 2):

An elaboration on @shabunc's answer, this uses Perl to strip comments (including inline comments), then print any lines containing anything other than whitespace.

```
$ perl -ne 's/;.*//; print if /\S/' data.txt
```

Explanation:

- `s/;.*//` uses the substitution operator (`s/<regex>/<replacement>/`) to replace instances of a semi-colon and everything following it on a line with the empty string.
- `print if /\S/` prints the line if it matches the regexp `\S`, which is a [character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes) matching all non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that I use, just substitute ';' with the comment character (e.g. '#' for many UNIX service configuration files):

```
grep -Ev '^[[:space:]]*;|^$' chan_dahdi.conf.sample | sed 's/;.*$//'
```

That gets rid of all whole-line comments (even if they have leading whitespace), and any comments that end non-comment lines, and succinctly removes blank lines from the output as well.  This may be possible without the pipeline (my sed- or awk-fu is admittedly not great), but it's so easy for me to understand (and remember), I figured I'd post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Example show only lines + do not show new lines or emtpy lines:

```
$ egrep -v '^(;|#|//)' /etc/ssh/sshd_config | tr '\n' ' '

 Protocol 2    SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV      PasswordAuthentication yes  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no   GSSAPIAuthentication yes GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes  UsePAM yes  AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS  X11Forwarding yes   Subsystem sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

OR

```
$ egrep -v '^(;|#|//|$)' /etc/ssh/sshd_config    

Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: The use of `egrep` is long deprecated. `grep -E` is the command you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

Will strip also empty lines

```
grep -E -v "^\s*($|;)" php.ini
```

Comment: `\s` is not guaranteed to be supported in plain `grep`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command to save the lines, excluding empty lines and lines starting with # in a new file

**`cat <file to be read> | egrep -v '^#|^$' > <file to be written at>`**

Comment: Useless `cat` pipe and `egrep` is depreciated and to be replaced with `grep -E` for extended expressions or just `grep -v`.