# How to grep on source code without catching comments

Tags: files, grep, source

I search a way to grep on source code without having sometimes false-positive because of comments. For instance if I search on foo on this .c source code :

```
/* 
 * foo has changed [...] and is now a 2-parameters function
 */
// foo(24)
foo(42, 28);
```

A naive `grep` will find 3 occurrences where I want only one. I have seen [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code) to do it on StackOverflow, but it does not fill my needs : PHP is not available on the platform. I have also found [this way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26235/how-can-i-cat-a-file-and-remove-commented-lines) for one-line comments, but it only solves a part of my problem.

I need to use classical scripting tools (awk, sed, bash, grep, etc) and I need it to be *fast* even if there are thousands of files.

Do you now if and how it's possible to grep on source code, and only source code ?

Comment: Building a [tags table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) might be a better approach, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try a naive approach to match non-comments like this:

```
 $ egrep -v "^(//|/\*| \*)" sourcecode
```

This will only inverse match against prefixed comments - that is lines starting with either `//`, `/*`, `*` or `*/` - and hence it'll not leave out blocks that are commented out with the `/*` and `*/` pair.

Comment: Modified slightly to work for indented comments: $ egrep -v "^[[:space:]]*((//|/\*| \*)" sourcecode

Answer (score 13):

grep works on pure text and does not know anything about the underlying syntax of your C program. Therefore, in order not search inside comments you have several options:

1. Strip C-comments before the search, you can do this using `gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E yourfile.c` For details, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code
2. Write/use some hacky half-working scripts like you have already found (e.g. they work by skipping lines starting with `//` or `/*`) in order to handle the details of all possible C/C++ comments (again, see the previous link for some scary testcases). Then you still may have false positives, but you do not have to preprocess anything.
3. Use more advanced tools for doing "semantic search" in the code. I have found "coccigrep": http://home.regit.org/software/coccigrep/ This kind of tools allows search for some specific language statements (i.e. an update of a structure with given name) and certainly they drop the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a specific variation for all of the rest of us late-comers to this question:

```
ls -1 src/*.c | xargs -i sh -c "echo;gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E {} 2>&1 | grep -wi -e one -e two -e three -n | sed 's:^:{}\::'" | cat -s
```

A list if C source files

```
ls -1 src/*.c
```

are piped to xargs, which executes the preprocessor in a child shell

```
gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E {} 2>&1
```

which is subsequently piped into a desired grep command

```
grep -wi -e one -e two -e three -n
```

which is then piped into sed to prefix each line with the current file name

```
sed 's:^:{}\::'
```

Finally, all the repeated blank lines are collapsed to single lines using cat:

```
cat -s
```

This works on a RHEL6 system, but I assume it is general enough for other *nix systems.

Comment: Good idea to use the tokenizer to remove comments. However this has the mistake of [parsing `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)